# Resource XML for validation and parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I have an XML file in the *res/xml* folder which I want to parse using `getXML()`.

But I also want to validate it first against an XSD schema.

How can I create a InputStreamReader for the XML file for validation?
It turns out that to use `openRawResource()` the file should be under *res/raw* or in *assets*

Comment: Since the XML file is pre-packaged, why can't the validation be done before it is added to the resources? Why does it have to be validated at runtime? Does the XSD change over time?

Comment: @Rajesh The method for validating is part of a library, the XSD file is not changing, but the users of the library may put their own XML in their project resources and I want to give them a way to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read it from the classpath, getclass -> getresourceasstream. For validation consider using the xerces lib.

Comment: `GetResourceAsStream()` gets a string argument, not a resource ID. I tried many forms, but always returns `null`. Any tip on how to access the "res/xml/<file>" using it?

Comment: If the resource is in the classpath, and depending on the package, you can do "Yourclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/xml/<filename>"))"

Comment: Note: I am using Xerces for validation. Not that I am locked on it, it seems to be the most used.

Comment: You are correct, it should be xerces (I was mixing another thread) - I've just edited the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put it under \res\xml\ folder. Then you can open it with:

```
 Resources res = activity.getResources();
 XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.your_resId);
```

Please follow below link for XMLResourceParser

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html

Comment: You don't actually answer the only question I wrote: How I create an InputStreamReader for the XML resource?